# Path to frontend files fails

Tags: hardhat, addresses, frontend

```js
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const fs = require("fs")

const FRONT_END_ADDRESS_FILE = `../../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/contractAddresses.json`
const FRONT_END_ABI_FILE = `../../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/abi.json`


module.exports = async function () {
  if (process.env.UPDATE_FRONT_END) {
    console.log("updating frontend...")
    updateContractAddresses()
    updateAbi()
  }
}

async function updateAbi() {
  const lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery")
  fs.writeFileSync(
    FRONT_END_ABI_FILE,
    lottery.interface.format(ethers.utils.FormatTypes.json)
  )
}

async function updateContractAddresses() {
  const lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery")
  const chainId = network.config.chainId.toString()
  const currentAddresses = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(FRONT_END_ADDRESS_FILE, "utf8") // utf-8 a way to convert to ASCII
  )
  if (chainId in contractAddress) {
    if (!contractAddress[chainId].includes(lottery.address)) {
      currentAddresses[chainId].push(lottery.address)
    }
  }
  {
    currentAddresses[chainId] = [lottery.address]
  }
  fs.writeFileSync(FRONT_END_ADDRESS_FILE, JSON.stringify(currentAddresses))
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "frontend"]
```

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/contractAddresses.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at updateContractAddresses (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\99-update-front-end.js:28:8)
```

> My file path is correct I have checked many times.. but still the same error is coming. This code is from Patrick Collins Blockchain Course.
> Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If both frontend and hardhat lottery code fall under same directory then in 4 and 5th line, instead of giving path as:

```js
const FRONT_END_ADDRESS_FILE = `../../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/contractAddresses.json`
const FRONT_END_ABI_FILE = `../../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/abi.json`
```

> Give path as:

```js
const FRONT_END_ADDRESS_FILE = `../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/contractAddresses.json`
const FRONT_END_ABI_FILE = `../nextjs-frontend-lottery/constants/abi.json`
```